# How can I ensure a modified file that is stashed gets committed?

Tags: git, git-stash

I'm using software that modifies the `Changes` file after publishing my distribution. This is a good thing because it reminds me to update this file (I always forget) before releasing my next version. This is fine when I do everything on the master branch.

Lately, however, I've tried to get in the habit of making changes on separate branches. So I have to stash the `Changes` file before I switch branches.

Is there a way to automatically pull the `Changes` file out of the stash when I switch back to master? If not, is there some way I can ensure it gets committed before issuing a `git push`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can run anything after you switched to *master* branch.  But you can certainly set up a **pre-push** script to run before push on the client side.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

The script could look into your log and see if there are any unapplied stashes

Comment: OK, yeah, thanks for jogging my memory. I added a little perl to pre-push.pl in the hooks directory. I just had it check to see if `git stash list` returned a value.